# Create an always-centered tab in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, alignment

In Word, I have a document whose header should have an item of text left-aligned, and then separate text that is center-aligned on the same line.

So far, to achieve this I have created a center tab at 3.25".  My problem is, the document periodically shifts between portrait and landscape, and the landscape pages would need a 4.5" tab to be centered.

Is there a way to force the center tab to simply be "center of page" without regard for a numerical distance?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If in Word 2007 or later, use the [Alignment Tab feature](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#AlignmentTabs)

It automatically adjusts to your layout/margins.

Here is what I've written on it in my chapter on Sections.

> In Headers and footers beginning with Word 2007 there are special
> margin-alignment tabs (left, center and right).These can be
> independent of the paragraph or style tab settings. [Use Alignment Tab
> Feature to set tabs relative to margins](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/use-word-2007s-new-alignment-tab-feature-to-align-text-with-margins/)
>
> Below are screenshots (Word 2010) from a page set up in both portrait
> and landscape orientations showing how these special tabs adapt to the
> change in orientation. (You reach this ribbon tab by double-clicking
> in a Header/footer or by selecting Edit Header/Edit Footer from the
> Insert Tab.)
>
> **Portrait Orientation**
>
> [image: screenshot of portrait page]
> The tab settings shown in the ruler are those for my Header style. The
> Alignment tabs appear to be set the same but are really oriented to
> the page margins rather than the tab settings in the style. This
> becomes apparent when this Section is switched to Landscape
> Orientation.
>
> **Landscape Orientation**
>
> [image: screenshot of landscape page]
>
> Note: Right click on the screenshot above and select "View Image" to
> see full size.
>
> Note that the tab settings in the Header style (shown on the ruler)
> are the same and the first line using those tabs is unchanged. The
> second line though uses the new Alignment Tabs and remains set well
> for this page orientation.
>
> Remember that by default the alignment tabs are independent not only
> of the tab settings but also the indent settings. In the example shown
> above the left and right indents were set at the margins, but they do
> not need to be. By default, the Alignment Tabs align to the margins,
> not the indents.
>
> [image: alignment tab dialog box]
>
> Alignment tabs can be used in the body of a document, but the control
> for it is in the Header and footer tools. You can add this dialog to
> your Quick Action Toolbar if you need them in the body. (I don't think
> you really want to do this, but could be wrong.)
>
> While the default with Alignment Tabs is to set them relative to the
> margins, they can also be set relative to the left and right paragraph
> indents. My usual Headers and footers have left and right indents
> outside the margins to emphasize that they are frames to the page. If
> I were using a right-alignment tab, I would want it relative to the
> indent so it would line up with the right indent setting. These
> indents change with orientation because they are relative to the
> margins.
>
> Unfortunately, the alignment tab will not go past the right margin!
> The right tab can still be set past the right margin and works, but
> that will not change with orientation.
>
> You can set alignment tabs relative to paragraph indents. In that
> case, they are influenced by paragraph formatting and styles.

The above is quoted from [my page on Sections](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#AlignmentTabs). That page is regularly edited and there may be more posted there at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

You may create a table extending over the entire header width with
three columns and one row.

Set the left cell to left-aligned, and the center cell to center-aligned,
and put your text in the left and center columns.